# How to update UITableView from another View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an scenario where:

ViewController1, `ViewController` displays a UITableView of 'communities' and has a button to join other communities which loads up another view.

ViewController2, `JoinCommunity` has a text field and a join button.

When a user enters a correct community code and clicks 'join' this registers the user into the community matching the code. At this point `JoinCommunity` is dismissed and `ViewController` appears.

My problem is that the UITableView in 'ViewController' does not update until the user logs out and logs back in.

I was advised the following line should achieve it but it didn't and so I still must be missing something :

`var communities = [String]() { didSet { communitiesTableView.reloadData()} }`

This is the code for ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UsernameSentDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var receiveUsername: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmailText: UILabel!
var userEmail: String?
var flag = false

var communities = [String]() { didSet { communitiesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}



@IBOutlet weak var communitiesTableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func unwindToHome(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {


}


//recieves email address from delegate from LoginViewController
func userLoggedIn(data: String) {

  userEmailText.text = data
     }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.communities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let title = self.communities[indexPath.row]

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = title

    return cell

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let loginViewController: LoginViewController = segue.destination as! LoginViewController
        loginViewController.delegate = self
    }

    if segue.identifier == "createCommunitySegue" {
        let createCommunityController: CreateNewCommunity = segue.destination as! CreateNewCommunity
        createCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text
    }

    if segue.identifier == "joinCommunitySegue" {
        let joinCommunityController: JoinCommunity = segue.destination as! JoinCommunity
        joinCommunityController.myEmail = userEmailText.text
    }

}

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if flag == true
    {
        print (flag)

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getDetails.php?");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "email=\(userEmailText.text)";
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                        if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                            self.communities = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!

                        }

                    }



                    } catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self
    self.communitiesTableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{

    communitiesTableView.reloadData()
   let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.bool(UserDefaults.standard)(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

    if(!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);
    }

}


}
```

And this is the code for JoinCommunity:

```
import UIKit

class JoinCommunity: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var communityCodeTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func goBackTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "exitJoin", sender: self)
}
var myEmail: String?

@IBAction func joinCommunityTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let communityCode = communityCodeTextField.text;
    if (communityCode!.isEmpty){
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "You must enter Community code");

        return;
    }else{

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/joinCommunity.php?");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";

        let postString = "code=\(communityCode!)&email=\(myEmail!)";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in


            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {


                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    do {

                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]


                        if let parseJSON = json {

                            let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                            if( returnValue == "Success")
                            {
                                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Joined new community", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);


                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){(action) in

                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                                }

                                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                            } else {


                                let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                                if(errorMessage != nil)
                                {

                                    self.displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: errorMessage!);

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    } catch{
                        print(error)
                    }



            }

        }

        task.resume()


    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil);

    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a flag from JoinCommunity to ViewController which was initially set to nil(optional type) or even a Boolean variable would do the trick. This can be achieved by prepareForSegue method as well as protocol delegate.

The method **viewWillAppear()** in life cycle of UIViewController executes every time when the UIViewController is pushed of comes into vision due to popping of another UIViewController on top of it in the navigation stack. So basically you just need to check the flag in **viewWillAppear()** whether the user has been successfully registered.

```
override func viewWillAppear()
{
    super.viewWillAppear()
    if flag == true
    {
        communitiesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

There could be a possibility that the user again registers after registering once. So disable this flag in the **viewWillDisappear()** method in life cycle of UIViewController the reason being that, in case the user does not actually register and pops the UIViewController it would lead to reloading of the table.

In case if the data to be reloaded is coming from a certain API you will need to call the web service in **willViewAppear()** method in life cycle of UIViewController and reload the table after you receive the response.

In case if you do not have a problem with reloading the data multiple times, simply reload your data in viewWillAppear(). **But it is not a good practice as it minimises the optimisation of the application due to reloading of data every single time without the user doing the registration.**

Comment: Thanks for such an in-depth and clear answer. I'm going to work through this tomorrow- I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Your welcome... Let me know if u need help by commenting here... Best of luck with your application

Comment: I have updated the code with your answer but i'm getting the error: "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" for the override func viewWillAppear().  I also don't know what to put in the () for superviewWillAppear(). Thanks

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewWillAppear(true)...your statements...}

Comment: Nearly there! So the flag is working and passing from false to true via segue when I join a new community.  But the table still isn't updating? I put print (flag) inside of the if flag == true and it does print true.

Comment: The array which you load in the table, are you taking measures to update it when anybody registers ?... I guess that might be the problem..... And inside the if condition also reload the data of the table using the function yourTableView.reloadData()

Comment: Only in that it writes to the database.  That was my initial problem, getting it to then update afterwards

Comment: So it is simply being updated in the backend... You will again have to fetch it as it did not get updated in the previous screen which is ViewController in your case.... You will have to call the api again in viewWillAppear.... I had mentioned it in my answer too..

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't quite understand before. So within the if flag == true, if this has been updated and the flag changed then the database has been updated so rerun the api? Or a new one that simply queries the database since the other one posted. I take it this is the full http.post request etc?

Comment: Yes... Because your ViewController has no idea of the update and this is how you would make it know... If u do not set the flag vieeWillAppear() will call the api every single time before your ViewController comes to screen... To avoid such scenario in case the user hasn't registered and just comes back to the previous screen...

Comment: Aah I get it.  I will have another go and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Yo... Awaiting your victory... 

Comment: Still not there! I have updated the question with new code for viewWillAppear which calls the API again.  But now once I have joined a community and returned back to the ViewController the table is empty?

Comment: reloadData should be inside the completion handler block.. as it is outside, the function is called even before you call the data as the response takes a little time to come to the device... So the basic idea here is call the reloadData function with the new data after you receive the response.

Comment: sorry, which is the completion handler block?

Comment: how can I print this line in the debug: if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                                self.communities = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!  I want to check that i'm receiving data into self.communities after the re-load.

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async block... That is wat executes when u receive the response so just a line bfr the block ends.... Reload your table.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code, on the ViewController, 'communities' is the array you used to populate the data on the TableView.Once the user joins a community successfully on the JoinCommunity  Controller. You are just dismissing the Controller. The 'communities' array on ViewController was never updated, and hence the old data is show. But when the user logs out and logs in you say the tableview gets updated.Iam guessing this is because on login your getting the communities associated with the user

Comment: Yes you are correct in what you say.  So I need to update the communities table or refresh/reload it once a user has registered.

Comment: yes so all you need is to get the new communities data, iam guessing you have an api setup for that.. make the api in viewWillAppear and then reload your tableview once you get the api response. Things should work fine